# Define a Recurrence Table involving other tables

Tags: recursion

I'm relatively new to using Mathematica. Previously I used Matlab, but lately I noticed that the numbers i got in both of them do not match (mostly it seems that Matlab lacks precision...).

The question is:
I need a nested table defined recursively, and based on it I'll calculate what I actually need. But the code

```
L = RecurrenceTable[
   {
    a[i] == -M[[i - 1]].Inverse[Psi[[i - 1]] + 
         L[[i - 1]].Lambda[[i - 1]]],
    a[2] == -M[[1]].Inverse[Psi[[1]]],
    a[1] == {{0}};
    },
   a,
   {i, 1, NN}
   ];
```

, where M, Psi and Lambda are nested tables themselves defined like

```
Psi = Table[Table[ __SOME FORMULAS__ , {i, 0, NN - n}, {j, 0, NN - n}], {n, 1, NN - 1}];
PrependTo[Psi, {{-c*P[NN]}}];
```

produces the following error:

```
Part::pspec: "Part specification -1+i is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. "
RecurrenceTable::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of Null in the first argument
```

Even though I did the same thing like in reference, but i got this error.
And considering the performance of numeric calculations - how can I improve it for the code above?

I would really appreciate any help.

---

```
NN = N[4, 50];

p[i_, j_] = Binomial[2*NN - i + j, i + j];

Ψ = 
  Table[Table[\[Piecewise]p[n + i, n + j] i == j 1 True, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}], {n, 0, 
    NN - 1}];

L = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
Do[AppendTo[L, Inverse[L[[i - 1]].Ψ[[i - 1]]]], {i, 2, NN}]
(*L=RecurrenceTable[{a[i]\[Equal]-M[[i-1]].Inverse[Ψ[[i-1]]+L[[i-1]].\
Λ[[i-1]]],a[2]\[Equal]-M[[1]].Inverse[Ψ[[1]]],a[1]\[Equal]{{0}}\
;},a,{i,1,NN}];*)

N[L, 5] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Look at the differences between = and :=

Comment: Those are immediate and delayed assignments. Is there any difference between them considering the "constant" values I should receive? (as all the parameters are predefined)

Comment: I'd like to take a further look at this: could you provide actual runnable code (using simple functions if you don't want to provide the originals)? In general, you can't use "=" when the right hand side is undefined, so you'd have to compute M, Psi, and Lambda first.

Comment: The RecurrenceTable code gives the Recursion Depth error if I substitute "=" with ":=".

Comment: It's quite hard to remove the "extra" code...
This is the maximum I could do (there are two versions inside comment):

`NN=N[4,50];

p[i_,j_]=Binomial[2*NN-i+j,i+j];

\[CapitalPsi]=Table[Table[\[Piecewise] p[n+i,n+j] i==j
1 True



,{i,0,1},{j,0,1}],{n,0,NN-1}];

L={{{1,2},{3,4}}};
Do[
AppendTo[
L,Inverse[L[[i-1]].\[CapitalPsi][[i-1]]]
],
{i,2,NN}
]
(*L=RecurrenceTable[
{
a[i]\[Equal]-M[[i-1]].Inverse[\[CapitalPsi][[i-1]]+L[[i-1]].\[CapitalLambda][[i-1]]],
a[2]==-M[[1]].Inverse[\[CapitalPsi][[1]]],
a[1]\[Equal]{{0}};
},
a,
{i,1,NN}
];*)

N[L,5] // MatrixForm`

How should I paste the code here?

Answer (score 1):

I should've mentioned this earlier, but, instead of RecurrenceTable 
try defining your recursions like this (using Fibbonaci numbers as an 
example):

```
fib[0] = 1; 
fib[1] = 1; 
fib[n_] := fib[n] = fib[n-1] + fib[n-2];
```

When you do fib[6] (for example), it will fib[6] and remember the 
value, making future recursions faster.

It also means you can nest recursions, since everything will be 
computed on an "as needed" basis.

More about this paradigm:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but this was the first thing I did.
Strangely, but it took more time to calculate the result this way (compared to the tabled version).
I should try and rewrite it from scratch. I'll try it tomorrow and tell the results.

Comment: When I wrote it the way you suggested, the time to calculate became enormous... Using Tables for a parameter value 30 it took me 1.7 seconds to calc, but this way it takes ~1 second for param = 5 and grows exponentially. Might be I wrote something incorrectly, but I double checked it.

Comment: If the rewritten code's not private, could you cut/paste it. I'd like to run it directly and see what's going on?