# Generate a random Fibonacci sequence

Tags: random, difference-equations

I want to generate the random sequence defined by $a_n = a_{n-2} + \beta(n)a_{n-1}$ where $\beta$ takes the values $\pm1$.  My attempt is:

```
 RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 2] + (-1)^(RandomInteger[{0, 1}])*a[n - 1], 
 a[0] == 1, a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 0, 10}]
```

But of course, `RandomInteger` only computes on the first loop, and then saves that value for all subsequence computations.  I found this solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63572/define-a-recurrence-table-involving-other-tables):

```
 r[n_] := RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
 rfib[0] = 1;
 rfib[1] = 1;
 rfib[n_] := rfib[n] = rfib[n - 2] + (-1)^r[n]*rfib[n - 1];
 Table[rfib[i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

However, I am wondering if my original intuition can be salvaged; i.e., is there a way to use `RandomInteger` inside `RecurrenceTable` and get a new integer each time?

Edit:

After posting this and looking for something else, I found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70031/sum-considers-randominteger-as-a-constant).  From this, I can write the code as

```
 rr[n_?NumericQ] := RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
 RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 2] + (-1)^(rr[n])*a[n - 1], 
 a[0] == 1, a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 0, 10}]
```

as I originally wanted to.

Comment: Where does this come from? Is it meant to model some particular physical problem?

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to directly implement the recursion:

```
Clear[a];
a[n_] := a[n] = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] a[n - 1] + a[n - 2];
a[0] = a[1] = 1;
```

For example, the first 20 terms might be:

```
a /@ Range[20]
{1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, -1, -3, -4, -1, 3, 4, 7, 3, -4}
```

Comment: Doesn't `RandomInteger[{-1,1}]` allow for the choice of zero? Other than that question, I see how this works. As a side note, I want my subtractions to go left to right, so I would put the random $\pm1$ with the $n-1$ term.

Comment: OK -- I've changed the placement of the randomness, and used `RandomChoice` instead of `RandomInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
func[a0_, a1_, n_] := Module[{r = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n]},
   FoldList[{#1[[2]], #1[[1]] + #2 #1[[2]]} &, {a0, a1}, r]] [[All, 
   1]]
```

Examples:

[image]

Comment: I was looking at `FoldList` but my ultimate goal was to generate the arcsine distribution that occurs when one varies the heads/tails probability of random Fibonacci sequences (when the coin is fair, you get Viswanath's number as the growth rate, and when the coin is 100% heads, you get the Golden Ratio,) so I needed a clean/fast way to get very large terms.  FoldList just didn't feel right to me for that.  Your example is quite nice, though.

Comment: @Trevor "Doesn't feel nice" isn't really an argument. :P Is there an actual practical problem you expect?  Performance?  Then I would make a compiled function, but still retain this basic design.  I did not pay attention when I posted my answer (as you can see it's very similar), but now that I read ubpdqn's carefully, I think his should perform better as it generates the random number in bulk (instead of calling `RandomChoice` in each iteration)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) or [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
NestList[
  {Last[#], {1, RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]}.#} &,
  {1, 1}, (* two initial values in the sequence *)
  100
][[All, 2]]
```

This is directly compilable:

```
cf = Compile[{{a0, _Integer}, {a1, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
  NestList[
    {Last[#], {1, RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]}.#} &,
    {a0, a1},
    n
    ][[All, 2]]
  ]
```

There is no MainEvaluate in the compiled function, but it will switch back to standard evaluation as soon as the values exceed $2^{63}-1$ (on a 64-bit machine).

Answer (score 0):

One can exploit the equivalence of evaluating three-term recurrence relations with repeated multiplication of $2\times 2$ matrices for this task. Just like in ubpdqn's solution, I use `RandomChoice[]` to generate a bunch of $\pm1$ multipliers all at once:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            With[{n = 20}, 
                 FoldList[Dot, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
                          Transpose[{{ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[1, n]}, 
                                     {ConstantArray[1, n], RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n]}},
                                    {2, 3, 1}]][[All, 2, 2]]]]
   {1, 2, -1, 3, -4, 7, -11, -4, -15, -19, -34,
    -53, -87, 34, -121, 155, -276, -121, -397, -518, 121}
```

Compare this with using `RecurrenceTable[]`:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            With[{n = 20}, pm = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n];
                 Quiet[RecurrenceTable[{y[k] == Indexed[pm, k] y[k - 1] + y[k - 2], 
                                        y[-1] == 1, y[0] == 1},
                                       y, {k, 0, n}], Indexed::partw]]]
```